# $1 in subject string when using preg_split

Tags: php, special-characters, preg-split

I want to split a text into an array where the delimiter is one or more of "\n", and then put the content of the array as elements in a unorder html-list. When I do this using preg_split when there is a $1 in the subject string I get a weird result. Just looking at the array resulting from the splitting the result is fine and the $1 seems not to have caused any problem, but when I loop over the array and make it into a html list it creates a different result then expected(see example bellow)

Like if this was the subject string:

"First line

Second line $1

Third line"

It should become:

- First line
- Second line $1
- Third line

But it becomes:

- First line
- Second lineFirst line
  Second line $1
  Third line
- Third line

Does anyone know why this happens?
Is $1 some kind of special html or php character with a reserved meaning?

This is the code I've written:

```
        $listElements = preg_split('/[\n]+/',$subject);
        $output = '<ul>';
        foreach ( $listElements as $val ) {
          $output .= '<li>' . $val . '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dollar symbols inside PHP strings has a weird effect to those who aren't familiar with it.

```
$foo = "BAR";
$example = "Hello, World! $foo $foo black sheep";
echo $example;
```

The above example echoes: `Hello, World! BAR BAR black sheep`. This is because the variable is expanded *within* the string.

A simple way of stopping this behaviour is by using single quotes: Changing the above example to `'Hello, World! $foo $foo black sheep';` will echo this: `Hello, World! $foo $foo black sheep`, and the dollars will be left in place.

Another way of stopping variables expanding inside double-quoted strings is by escaping them with a backslash:

```
$example = "Hello, World! \$foo \$foo black sheep";
```

will echo:

`Hello, World! $foo $foo black sheep`

---

In your example, I would assume that `$val` has a dollar symbol in it, which needs escaping.

Comment: Oki, good to know. But I'm still not sure if this is my problem, or how to fix it. I don't use double quotes anywhere so that's not the problem. How do do I "escape" the $1? (And also I'm a bit curious about what variable $1 is. I never set it in my code so where does it come from?)

Comment: Ah! I figured out the problem. $output is later used in preg_replace() and I had captured a something that is stored in $1. I can rewrite the pattern so that nothing is stored in $1, but isn't $0 always set if I make a match for my pattern? So I guess that needs escaping.